# solenoid hammer trigger control

Tags: solenoid, trigger

I am new here and a newbie regarding electronics, I shoot PCP air rifles and have a small project regarding the air rifle. The shooting mechanism is consisted of a trigger releasing a spring loaded hammer to open the air valve with 110~130 bar of pressure behind it. The hammer is tensioned with the spring. The idea is to replace the mechanical trigger (hammer) with a solenoid and variable power output. I was thinking of using a solenoid with capacitor discharge circuit and a 555 timer. The solenoid will be powered for a fractions of a second to hit open the valve, I was thinking of 2 ways to do this:

1. Limit the charge voltage to be discharged to the solenoid to have variable power
2. Play with the time the solenoid is powered.

I need to have the variable power to control the speed of the PCP.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can i control the power output and open time of the solenoid?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the timing method you have in mind. A 555 probably won't be accurate enough to do what you need. I suspect that the timing of the trigger pulse will be fairly sensitive and you'll want to drive it with a half bridge to turn it off quickly as well, and not just let the spring make it return.

So at the very least (in my opinion), you need a micro-controller like an [Arduino](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11113) (and possibly a [programmer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9873?_ga=1.119976586.343632447.1413272730)), a [Solenoid](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11015) strong enough to push the pin, and a half [bridge](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9457) to drive the solenoid.

Comment: I think other designs use a solenoid over powered for fraction of a sec to achieve the required power. I was thinking of arduino but i like to keep the cost down, maybe pic controler?? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: An Arduino is a development platform built around an AVR, if you want to go with a PIC that's fine as well. Small PIC development boards won't be much cheaper though (if at all).

Comment: Using precision components and CMOS variants of 555 could do the trick. Depending upon where you live, a uC might cost the same as a 555 or TTL/CMOS logic. For me, PIC16f676 costs 1/5th of an AVR and about the same cost of a 7555 or TLC555. With enough luck in backpack, PIC10F series might be even cheaper (e.g. http://www.aliexpress.com).